# Exporting a preg_match into an array

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

Hey I'm trying to put exactly what is selected into an array, and it's not working. Here's what I've got:

```
$stripped = "listing requirements. $ 669,647,431,200 P/E Ratio: 17.75 Forward P/E(1y) A widel";
$pattern = '/P\/E+\s+\w\w\w\w\w\W\s\w\w\W\w\w/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r ($matches);
```

Basically I want it to just output "P/E Ratio: 17.75" into an array. Nothing else.

I realized my form also wouldn't work if the P/E was say, 114.13. How could I just get it to select the next two "words"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the regex as

```
P\/E Ratio: [\d.]+
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/tK9rR0/1

```
$subject = "listing requirements. $ 669,647,431,200 P/E Ratio: 17.75 Forward P/E(1y) A widel";
$pattern = '/P\/E Ratio: [\d.]+/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r ($matches);
```

Will give an output

```
Array ( [0] => P/E Ratio: 17.75 )
```

Comment: Thank you! This code is super simple and works perfect.